# How to fix/prevent overlapping timecode - SBV to SRT conversion (Exporting from Youtube to upload to LinkedIn)

Tags: caption, srt

I am uploading a video to LinkedIn and want to add subtitles.

To achieve this I have exported an SBV file from YouTube and converted it to SRT, however the SRT file doesn't read correctly back into LinkedIn, giving me an error about the timecode referenced being in the past.

Looking at both the original SBV file and the converted SRT file I can see what's happening and suspect it's because Youtube has multi-line subtitles..? So the captions end up essentially overlapping? (At least, that's what it looks like based on the timecode, snippet below).

```
// Sample from the SBV file generated by YouTube:

0:00:14.070,0:00:20.670
theatre workshop and two weeks ago I

0:00:18.029,0:00:22.680
found out that two were vegetarian and

0:00:20.670,0:00:24.359
one was gluten-free but that's fine

0:00:22.680,0:00:27.240
that's not a challenge I can do that a
```

```
// Sample from converted SRT file:

5
00:00:14,070 --> 00:00:20,670
theatre workshop and two weeks ago I

6
00:00:18,029 --> 00:00:22,680
found out that two were vegetarian and

7
00:00:20,670 --> 00:00:24,359
one was gluten-free but that's fine

8
00:00:22,680 --> 00:00:27,240
that's not a challenge I can do that a
```

I was able to resolve this by manually editing the timecode in the SRT so that each new line/caption references timecode that is sequentially after the previous. This fixed the issue and I was able to add the SRT file successfully, but the process was laborious.

Can anyone suggest a way to generate the SRT file correctly, so it doesn't need to be manually edited?

Answer (score 0):

I also had overlapping subtitles timing issue

This helped me: https://gist.github.com/nimatrueway/4589700f49c691e5413c5b2df4d02f4f

Kudos to Nima Taheri  https://github.com/nimatrueway

I have uploaded my subtitles to YouTube, downloaded it as SRT, Ran the go fixer and uploaded it again as subtitles file, it fixed it.